# Some new questions on Rademacher complexity

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities, computational-complexity, machine-learning

For $A\subset R^n$,$A=(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n)$, $\sigma_i$ are Rademacher random variable.

1. Is $|\mathbb{E}_\sigma \inf_{a\in A}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_ia_i| \le |\mathbb{E}_\sigma \sup_{a\in A}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_ia_i| $
2. Is there any result on the absolute value version of Rademacher complexity, i.e.
   $S(A) = \mathbb{E}_\sigma \sup_{a\in A}|\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_ia_i|$

the "result" means, e.g. contract inequality, upper bound in some cases

Comment: Do you mean to assume that the $\sigma_i$ are independent? If so, the vectors $\sigma$ and $-\sigma$ have the same distribution. Then $\inf_{a\in A}\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_ia_i$, which is the same as $-\sup_{a\in A}\sum_{i=1}^n(-\sigma_i)a_i$, has the same distribution as $-\sup_{a\in A}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i a_i$, and so both sides of 1. are the same.